# Здравствуйте, как мне обойти recaptcha v2 на сайте через python, с последующим входом на сайт и созданием куки файлов?

Tags: python, api, recaptcha

как мне обойти recaptcha v2 на сайте через python, с последующим входом на сайт и созданием куки файлов, желательно не используя Selenium.

```
import requests
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


pageurl = 'https://unu.im/account/login'
method = 'userrecaptcha'
googlekey = '6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-'
key = 'key captcha_guru'
r = requests.get('http://api.captcha.guru/in.php?key='+key +
                 '&method='+method+'&googlekey='+googlekey+'&pageurl='+pageurl)
print(r.text)
if r.ok and r.text.find('OK') > -1:
    reqid = r.text[r.text.find('|')+1:]
for timeout in range(40):
    r = requests.get('http://api.captcha.guru/res.php?key=' +
                     key+'&action=get&id='+reqid)
    if r.text.find('CAPCHA_NOT_READY') > -1:
        time.sleep(10)
    if r.text.find('ERROR') > -1:
        print(r.text)
        break
    if r.text.find('OK') > -1:
        a = r.text[r.text.find('|')+1:]
        time.sleep(10)
        data = {
            'email': 'email',
            'password': 'password',
            'g-recaptcha-response': a,
            'submit': 1
        }
        req = requests.post(pageurl, data=data)
        break
print(a)
print(req)
ua = UserAgent()

ua_chrome = ua.chrome


# test headers
headers = {
    'user-agent': f'{ua_chrome}',
}


with open('index.html', 'w+') as file:
    file.read()
    file.write(req)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Люди долго учатся, потом создают продукт препятсвующий автоматической авторизации, потом находятся люди которые учились не меньше, и взломают то, что сделали первые ... (цикл повторяется энное к-во раз в процессе которых защита совершенствуется), потом приходит чувак, парсящий html даже не регулярками, он их парсит через `str.find()` и хочет поучавствовать в этих бегах. Удачи.

Comment: мне кажется это невозможно сделать тем как ты хочешь

Comment: Есть другой вариант, если конечно он подойдёт, у меня есть файл с куками, которые сделал модуль pickle с помощью selenium, как мне это файл загрузить в requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя долгое время с этого вопроса, держите его ответ:
Первым делом создаёте отдельный скрипт, где будет открываться браузер и создаваться куки файл(-ы):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from auth_data import *
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pickle


# options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua = UserAgent()

uac = ua.chrome

options.add_argument(f'user-agent={uac}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'path-driver', options=options)

driver.get('Login page')
login_input = driver.find_element(
    By.NAME, 'Name login input').send_keys('Your Login')
password_input = driver.find_element(
    By.NAME, 'Name password input').send_keys('Your password')
# За это время в браузере решаете каптчу, можете поставить сколько угодно врeмени
time.sleep(10)
# нажимаете на кнопку авторизации
login_bttn = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, 'Путь до кнопки авторизации').click()

# Создаём файл куки
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('Имя файла куки', 'wb'))
#И на всякий случай ждёте немного времени (по желанию)
time.sleep(10)
```

Теперь файл с парсером вставляете полученые куки:

```
import requests
import pickle
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

session = requests.Session()

for cookies in pickle.load(open('Имя файла с куки', 'rb')):
    session.cookies.set(cookies['name'], cookies['value'])

time.sleep(10)  # Задержка для загрузки куки

ua = UserAgent()
ua_chrome = ua.chrome
headers = {
    'user-agent': f'{ua_chrome}'
}

a = session.get('Сайт, на котором нужны куки', headers=headers)
with open('index.html', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(a.text)
    f.close()
    #Ура, вы залогинились!
```

Спасибо [Namerek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/397399/namerek), за то . что пожелал удачи :3

Comment: Классный вариант вообще!

Comment: Сам долго мучался, сам и сделал)